# Opening a Diff in the currently open instance of Visual Studio 2012

Tags: diff, visual-studio-2012

So I've been using the VS2012 diff tool with git recently and i dare say  really like it. What's causing issues though is opening the diff using the command "devenv.exe -diff $file1 $file2" opens the diff in a new window (which takes aaaages). Anyone know if it's possible to open the diff in the current instance of Visual Studio and not a new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using VS2013. Since I'm always running devenv.exe as Administrator, I've managed to achieve this by launching cmd (or app that calls -diff) with Administrator permissions also.

Answer (score 14):

You might want to look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17664677/2410220): use `Tools.DiffFiles` in the Command window.

Comment: Not what I'm after unfortunately. I need to be able to add an entry to my gitconfig in the format  `devenv.exe -diff $file1 $file2"`, but not open a new instance of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

In the solution explorer right-click on a file then choose compare. You will then have the option of selecting your files

Comment: Sorry, I am speaking in particular about opening a diff via command line (for use with git in this particular situation).

Answer (score 0):

This is the vs2017 default behaviour